# How to manually authenticate with Digest Auth?

Tags: php, rest, authentication, digest, digest-authentication

I have a restful api I want to access, and my app has its own login form. I want to use those credentials every time I try to access my rest resources. The problem is, since I´m using HTTP Digest, every time I send the 401 Unauthorized header, an ugly browser-specific login form will pop. How do I override this? How do I pass the username and password to the Digest Auth without using the default form? Not sure if my question is specific enough...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just specify login and password in the url in the form of

```
http://username:password@domain/url
```

Comment: I actually tried this and is working fine, thanks, but now I have a question: This means that I have to store the raw username and password when the user first logs in, in order to call my rest resources like this: http://username:password@domain/resource; isn't this a flaw in the security?

Comment: @Guj Mil: you need to have username and passwords in plaintext when you perform the request. Temporarily between requests you may have them encrypted